# NonlinearModelFit::nrnum error

Tags: fitting, warning-messages

I'm trying to fit data (including some small negative numbers at both extremes) to a normal distribution.

```
model2[x_, m_, s_] := (1/(s Sqrt[2 Pi]))*E^((-1* (x - m)^2)/(2 s^2))
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data[[1, 11 ;;]], {model2[x, m, s], s > 0}, {m, s}, x]
```

However, when I run this I get an error:

> NonlinearModelFit::nrnum: The function value 1/2 (4.4016*10^6+(5.567805442689453*10^-3474357-)^2) is not a real number at {m,s} = {1.,1.}. >>

I don't know how it could get this value, and I've already tried constraining s to be positive to avoid divide by zero error. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share some or all of your data?

Comment: Maybe I'm too impatient to wait for the data (which I understand can't always be shared) but the curve you show is a normal density that integrates to 1.0 rather than a scalable curve form that has the shape of a normal.  If you just have observations from a normal distribution, then calculating the sample mean and sample standard deviation and plugging those into m and s will give you the estimates of the necessary parameters.  If you have binned data, then there is another method that should be used.

Comment: The error indicates your data probably  contains some non-numeric junk.  Try this: `ArrayQ[data[[1, 11 ;;]], 2, Element[#, Reals] &]`  (the second arg is `1` or `2` depending on the dimension of the data )